# Icon images not loading fast enough

Tags: java, swing, load, icons, jpanel

I have an array of `JPanel` with `JLabel` with icons that represent a seat at a theater, all of them are generated using loop.
Upon loading the seats,  those that are already booked need to have a different image icon. So `if(){}` check is performed on all the seats to change the label icon if the seat is booked, after they are generated.

But the image icon I have on my disk is not loading fast enough so sometimes the panel adds only to the last one booked or not at all.
Every of those panels that represent the chairs has also `MouseListener` interfaces added to them. So also on mouse hover or click `ImageIcon` objects added to the panels are changed, there is too much delay when this happens. I'm thinking  that has to do with the images being on the disk!.

1. How can I load and store those icon images 2,78 KB in size in memory and refer to it in memory, so it wont be delayed reading them?
2. When a seat is clicked I need to change the label image of that seat and remove mouse listener from that seat. Is there a way to remove the mouse listener to that particular seat without referring to a specific mouse listener.  I needed to do that outside of the mouse listener itself!

   ```
   panel.removeAll();
   ```

   Does not remove the mouse listener added upon generating the panels.

```all
public void drawSeats(int ammountSeat, int localLength, int localWidth) {

        pnlSeatsHolder = new JPanel();
        pnlSeatsHolder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(localLength * 40,localLength * 45)); 
        pnlSeatsHolder.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        for (int d = 0; d <= (ammountSeat); d++) {
            imgIconYellow = new ImageIcon("seatYellow.png");
            imgIconBlue = new ImageIcon("seatBlue.png");
            imgIconRed = new ImageIcon("seatRed.png");

            JButton chairs = new JButton();
            chairs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 40));    
            pnlSeatsHolder.add(chairs);

            chairs.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listSeatsObjects.size(); i++) {
                        if (listSeatsObjects.get(i).equals(e.getSource())) {
                /*I need to do this also outside of this method! how can i refer to this MouseListener
                 * to forexample do the equivalent of chairs.removeMouseListener(this);*/
                            chairs.removeAll();
                            chairs.setIcon(imgIconRed);
                            chairs.repaint();
                            chairs.removeMouseListener(this);
                            // send information of the chair somewhere else
                        }
                    }
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    // chairs.setBackground(Color.blue);
                    chairs.removeAll();
                    chairs.setIcon(imgIconBlue);
                    chairs.repaint();
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    // chairs.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    chairs.removeAll();
                    chairs.setIcon(imgIconYellow);
                    chairs.repaint();
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

so this is the method it self that draws the seats when called. I did some modification as @AndrewThompson suggested, instead of JPanels i use now JButtons, but what happens is that the images are not loaded at all on to the buttons.. what am i missing? neither on mouse hover either.. tho it does work if i had for example charis.setBackgroundColor(); on hover or click.. so i now i need to rather change the buttons images when clicked and on hover, i've tried chairs.chairs.setRolloverIcon(); and .setIcon(); both not working as well. what is wrong. my images are in the same directory as the class files.. so that cant be the issue..

int localLength, int localWidth is the size of the the rooms that seats will be drawn in. about 1m^2/seat

Comment: *"how can i load and store those icon images"* How many (different) images are there in total?

Comment: You should also consider using a `JButton` or `JToggleButton` with an `ActionListener` instead of `JLabel` with `MouseListener`.  Not only does a button react to both mouse & keyboard input, but the button has support for changing the icon on hover, press, focus etc.

Comment: 3. Red seat, Blue, && Yellow, Amout of seats generated varies depending on other perimetre. but those 3 images are shared among all seats generated.

yellow is added to all at start.  on mousehover it chagnes to blue, when mouse clicked it changes to red.

Comment: 1) Just read them during the application start-up and keep a reference in a class (maybe Singleton) to access/use them when needed. 2) See @AndrewThompson comments.

Comment: I've written a really long school project shcool. i relly dont want to change too much. Solved and it's working but this lag tho is annoying. forexample this is what needs to be done upon mouse hoover:

pnlChair.removeAll();
pnlChair.add(lblseatRed);
pnlChair.repaint();
pnlChair.removeMouseListener(this);

Comment: @AndrewThompson .. did as you suggested and seemed the right thing to do but is not working please check my code above, why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

For three images, load them when the class is initialized and store them as attributes of the class.  Of course, each of the 3 images can be used in as many icons as needed.